# background image not showing in different html page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple bootstrap template, but i facing a problem. My problem is my background image not showing.

```
.asheader{
    background:url('asset/header_bg.png')no-repeat;
    background-repeat:norepeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.asfooter{
    background-image:url('asset/footer_bg.png');
    background-repeat:norepeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

i wonder why, because i have 2 html pages `index.html` and `index2.html` , in my `index.html` the background img is showsing up, but in `index2.html` the background is not showing up.

here is my `index.html` fullpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/flexslider.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
@media (max-width: 766px){
    img{
        width:50%;
        height:50%;
    }
}
  @media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    } 


}
 .navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  }
  #Intro {
      display: inline-block;
  }
  #topnavbar {
    top: 15px;
   }

.carousel {
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lookbook{
   width:600px;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0 auto;

  }
.lookbook > h2{
   text-align: center;
}

.ladiesroom{
   width:600px;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ladiesroom > h2{
   text-align: center;
}


.afterlookbook{
   width:630px;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.instagram{
   width:630px;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
  }
.instagram > h2{
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.c-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar a {
    color: black;
}

blockquote{
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 2px 0px 2px 0px #000;
  border: none;

}
blockquote:before {
  color: #ccc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote p {
  display: inline;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img, 
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img{
width: 100%; /* use this, or not */
margin: auto;
}
.container-fluid
{
  padding-top: 50px;


  background-size:100% auto;
}
.top-buffer { margin-top:10px; }
.asheader{
    background:url('asset/header_bg.png')no-repeat;
    background-repeat:norepeat;
    background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.asfooter{
    background-image:url('asset/footer_bg.png');
    background-repeat:norepeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">

 <div class="asheader">
<div id="Intro" class="col-md-offset-5">
  <img src="asset/logo_hitam.png" width="200px" height="50px">
</div>

    <nav id="topnavbar" class="navbar transparent">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ladies Room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Need Help?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- -->
    </nav>
    <div class="c-wrapper">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="active item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/000">
      </div>
      <div class="item"> 
             <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/000">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
     </div>
</div>

  <div class="lookbook">
      <h2>Lookbook</h2>
      <div id="" class="flexslider slide_thumb">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="afterlookbook">

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-12">
     <img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
       <img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
    <br><br>
      <div class="top-buffer col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-sm-12">
            <img src="asset/quiz_mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></div>

        <div class="top-buffer col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-sm-12">

       <img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></div>

  </div>
 </div>
  <blockquote style="border-top:5px solid black; border-bottom: 5px solid black;" class="quotes">
  <p>asdfasdfasdfasdf</p>
  </blockquote>

  <div class="asfooter">
<div class="ladiesroom">
      <h2>Ladie's Room</h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>

<div class="instagram">
<h2>See The Latest On Instagram</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</div>

</div>

</div>
<script defer src="asset/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar').toggleClass('navbar-default');
    }
    else {
      $('.navbar').toggleClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-default');
    }
    })
})
 $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.slide_thumb').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                asNavFor: '.slide_thumb',
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                minItems: 2,
                maxItems: 4
            });
            });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is `index2.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/flexslider.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      @media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    } 


}
 .navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {

    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
  }
   #topnavbar,#bottomnavbar{
    top: 15px;
   }
   #bottomnavbar{
    height:100px;
   }

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.c-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.navbar a {
    color: black;
}

.center-block {  
  margin-right: auto;  
  margin-left: auto;  
}  
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
.asheader{
  background:url('asset/header_bg.png')no-repeat;
  background-repeat:norepeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.asfooter{
  background-image:url('asset/footer_bg.png');
  background-repeat:norepeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

blockquote{
  border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="asheader">
    <div id="Intro" class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-5">
      <img src="asset/logo_hitam.png" width="200px" height="50px">
    </div>


    <nav id="topnavbar" class="navbar transparent col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ladies Room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Need Help?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- -->
    </nav>


      <div class="c-wrapper">
     <div id="myCarousel" style="background:black !important" class="carousel slide col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="active item">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/000">
      </div>
      <div class="item"> 
             <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/000">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
     </div>
</div>


    <div class="lookbook col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
      <h2>Lookbook</h2>
      <div id="" class="flexslider slide_thumb">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </div>



<div class="grid col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></td>
            <td>     <img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>     
                <img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
            </td>
            <td>     <img src="asset/mini-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>



    <div class="quote col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
 <blockquote class="quote-card">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
              </p>

              <cite>
                Lorem I psum
              </cite>
            </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="lookbook col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
      <h2>Ladies Room</h2>
      <div id="" class="flexslider slide_thumb">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="asset/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="instagram col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
<h2>See The Latest On Instagram</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120"></td>
            <td><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

</div>
 <div class="instagram col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 text-center">
<h2>SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h2>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </span>
</div>

</div>
      <nav id="bottomnavbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse col-md-12 fixed-bottom">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Promo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Competition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ladies Room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Need Help?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--- -->
    </nav>
    </div>
 <script  src="asset/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar').toggleClass('navbar-default');
    }
    else {
      $('.navbar').toggleClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-default');
    }
    })
})
 $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.slide_thumb').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                asNavFor: '.slide_thumb',
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                minItems: 4,
                maxItems: 4
            });
            });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

any solution ? thanks in advance. Here is my folder structure

[image]

I do a test in `index2`. i add this in my css

```
body{
    background:url('asset/header_bg.png')no-repeat;

}
```

the image is showing up. So, it's 100% not a path problem

Comment: Are `index` and `index2` in the same folder? Have you tried holding down `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon (to clear the cache)? Also, there's a **lot** of code there -- can you please ensure you provide a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes both of them in same folder

Comment: @ObsidianAge Imo, is because at index i not using bootstrap `col-md-` and in index2 i use it. is it become a problem ?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it might not be working; the wrong file path, CSS declarations not properly closed, the cache not properly clearing, etc. However, all of those appear correct in your case. Bootstrap shouldn't be interfering with the 'load' in that sense, though it may be interfering with the **display**. If you use the F12 Developer Tools, do you see the background-image being applied on both elements?

Comment: @ObsidianAge my `F12` is clear, have you see my updated question ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fact that the `<blockquote>` element is missing in the second html document is causing the backgroud-image dimensions to be missing too (not set). Somehow the size of the background-image is depending on that element. Adding some dimensions to the `quote` class seems to fix it, i.e.:

```
.quotes {
  height: 600px;
}
```

I hope it helps!